# Jmeter -> What if I am using multiple HTTP Request Samplers?

Tags: jmeter

My questions are as follows :

1) I have added 10 HTTP Samplers in the Test plan , then what difference can they make on 
the load testing of the website ?

2) When we are using jmeter for load testing how can we measure the failure of the website due to load i.e. the parameters of the failure of a website under load testing.

Comment: 1) What sort of difference you are referencing in point no.1

Comment: difference on load factor which will be applicable for load testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you have 1 sampler, 1 thread and 1 loop - the thread will execute 1 sampler and exit.
2. If you have 10 samplers, 1 thread and 1 loop - the thread will execute all 10 samplers consecutively and exit.
3. If you have 10 samplers, 10 threads and 1 loop - each of 10 threads will execute each of 10 samplers (100 executions in total)
4. If you have 10 samplers, 10 threads and 10 loops - each of 10 threads will execute each of 10 samplers for 10 times, 1000 executions in total.

Depending on what sampler(s) do and how fast server response is you can get from 1 to 10 concurrent users.

If you need to hammer one endpoint there is no sense in copy-pasting samplers, you can use [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) instead.

To precisely control the load you need the following:

- Calculate reasonable ramp-up and iterations numbers (or use a plugin like [Ultimate Thread Group](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/), which provides easy way of load test scenario definition)
- If you're looking for generating a spike, like 1000 simultaneous requests, take a look into [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer)
- If you're trying to simulate something like "100 requests per second" - it would be [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer)
- To analyze load test report open test results file with one (or several) [JMeter's listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners), personally I would go for [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report). Also see [The Load Reports guide](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65153-the-load-reports) for all major performance metrics explained.

Comment: Thanks sir [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562554/jmeter-what-if-i-am-using-multiple-http-request-samplers/25563260#25563260]