# Jmeter- how do i know when i need to create new thread or user?

Tags: testing, jmeter

I am a tester. 
I went through Apache Jmeter. 
I understood some features but still I have some doubts regarding its features.

I am testing a web based application, which has number of web pages including log-in page.

I need to do performance testing on it.

1. I want to know when i should create a new user ?
2. How number of loops affects the results?
3. Should i run each HTTP request one by one or after creating all HTTP request i can run all requests at a time?
   (if i set loop=2, and create a HTTP request and click on run then result comes in 2 iterations & when i create new HTTP request & again click on run then i am getting result in 2 iterations for recent HTTP request & for previous one it will be in 4 iterations
   but when i run all HTTP request at a time then get result for all HTTP request in 2 iterations only)

I want to know that which process is right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers are :

**Answer for question 1:**

- At Thread group -> Number of threads =( number of users) means if you have created 100 threads then it will be equal to 100 users. Ensure you follow best practices when increasing number of threads:

  - http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html
  - http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/
- Thread group -> Ramp up time is an important factor it means the time delay between 1 thread start and the other. Please refer the following [Jmeter -> What if I am using multiple HTTP Request Samplers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562554/jmeter-what-if-i-am-using-multiple-http-request-samplers]) and note that if the rampup time is 0 (zero) it means all of your threads will start concurrently.

**Answer to question 2:**

Number of loop means the number of times the samples inside the element will be ran.
If you have 10 threads and number of loop is 10 means each thread will run for 10 times and since there are 10 threads total number samples = (number of loop count)*(number of threads)
i.e. here 10 * 10 =100

**Answer to question 3:**

please read the link 
[[Jmeter -> What if I am using multiple HTTP Request Samplers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562554/jmeter-what-if-i-am-using-multiple-http-request-samplers]) additionally you can use Loop or ForEeach controller for this purpose.

Please read the following for additional knowledge:

- https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2546/where-can-i-find-good-jmeter-tutorials
- http://lincolnloop.com/blog/load-testing-jmeter-part-1-getting-started/

[Ultimate Thread Group An Important Aspect](http://testingfreak.com/tools/jmeter/ultimate-thread-group/)